# AeroFS doesn't start

Tags: windows-7, installation, aerofs

I have just installed [AeroFS](https://aerofs.com/). The AeroFS folder that was supposed to be created after the installation hasn't been created. When starting the AeroFS application nothing happens and there is no AeroFS tray icon. I have tried to reinstall AeroFS several times and still encounter the problem.

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: @terdon: Windows 7. Just added that to the question.